# Is there ANY way to run windows software on ARM processor (Odroid)

Tags: linux, windows, arm, wine

I have looked everywhere but didn't find a solution. I couldn't get exogear to work either because you can't install wine on odroid.

thanks in advance for ANY solutions

Comment: Strictly speaking, you *can* run Windows software built for ARM using Wine on ARM ;-). But I imagine that’s not what you’re after.

Comment: You can also theoretically run windows software build for x86/amd64 on ARM, but then you would need to emulate the instruction set and as far as I know that is generally not advisable to try on ARM.

Comment: Well, you could [put something together with Wine and Qemu](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM#Running_Windows.2Fx86_Applications) but it will be slow.

Comment: I can confirm that the Wine + QEMU thing works (I've done it before), and it is _painfully_ slow, even on a reasonably high-end ARM CPU.  Somewhat ironically, the reverse (running Windows ARM programs on an x86 Linux box) is actually significantly faster (it's easier to emulate an ARM CPU on x86 than to emulate an x86 CPU on ARM).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That is due to the fact that ARM is a reduce set intrusction CPU and X86 are Complex insctruction set, which basically mean that a x86_64 CPU knows every instruction an ARM CPU use while the contrary is absolutly false. So it's way harder to emulate X86 CPU architecture which explains why emulation of modern console using complex instruction set CPU  such as PS3/XBox... are way more complex to emulate

Comment: I don't think it's much of a RISC vs CISC issue.  ARM processors are generally low power while x86 are high power.  Both architectures have several extensions (eg SIMD, AES) and both internally run a RISC core (x86 core translates their own code)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, No.
Long answer, as mention in the comment, you could [Wine for ARM](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM) though it's made to run Windows ARM program not Windows x86 or x64.
[X86 Emulation or x86 VM on ARM platform are not very developed at all](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/249292-microsoft-declares-windows-10-arm-devices-will-run-x86-code-near-native-speed)(except with very strange strategy for example).

**Edit:**
Well I've spoke a bit too quick... [You might maybe perhaps make something that works](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM#Running_Windows.2Fx86_Applications) almost but it would most likely be only for experimental use and not production.